# Microsoft Graph Azure AD API filter users with access to Azure only

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

What is the correct query to get all of the users within an organization who are actively using Azure? We do not want all of the users in the organization.

Thanks,

Vince

Palo Alto Networks

Answer (score 1):

Are you aiming to query users based on whether they have logged into Azure, or are you trying to check if the users were added originally in Azure AD or came from a different source?

You can list user sign-ins using the graph API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-beta

You can also list the source of users (whether they originated in Azure Active Directory or On-Premises) using either Powershell or the portal.

```
Get-AzureADUser | Where {$_.DirSyncEnabled -ne $true}
```

Comment: Thanks Marilee. We're actually trying to monitor Azure users specifically for compliance requirements, and monitor accounts for unusual activity or any configurations that are not configured according to best practices. They key is we only want to do this for the azure users.

Comment: For your own Azure AD users?

Comment: no, we would monitor these accounts as part of a cloud monitoring service.